# Configuring app's basename in react-router

Tags: react-router, react-router-redux

I'm struggling a bit with react-router 2.x configuration, specifically app basename.

I've an application which may have different base root throughout its lifecycle. For instance:

- `/` in development
- `/users` in production
- `/account` in production after migration

The basename comes into play in several places:

- static asset compilation in Webpack
- react-router main configuration
- specifying redirect routes in redux actions
- providing something like `redirectUrl` to API calls

My current solution is to have an ENV variable and make it available both to Webpack and to the app itself by injecting `window.defs` via an Express server, but I still end up having things like `${defs.APP_BASENAME}/signin` in way too many places throughout the app.

How can I abstract the app base, or at least tuck it away in a single location? I should be able to specify the base route in Router's config, and then simply use relative routes somehow, right? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 12):

You can decorate your `history` with a [basename](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/docs/guides/Histories.md#examples). You could mix this with a `DefinePlugin` in your Webpack configuration to specify which basename should be used.

```
// webpack.config.js
new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
  BASENAME: '/users'
})

// somewhere in your application
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHistory } from 'history'

const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: BASENAME
})
```

Given the basename: `/users`, React Router will ignore the `/users` at the beginning of the pathname so:

1. The URL `/users` is internally matched by the path `/`
2. The URL `/users/profile` matches the path `/profile`.

Similarly, you do not have to append the basename to the path when you are navigating within your application.

3. `<Link to='/friends'>Friends</Link>` will navigate to `/friends` internally, but the URL in the location bar will be `/users/friends`.

Answer (score 7):

Today I ran into the same issue:
On my localhost I let an NGINX serve the stuff in the root context, but on my prod server, an Apache serves the stuff from a subdirectory...

Inspired by the answer from Paul S and inspired by the infos here:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/353

I got the for me working solution:

In the Webpack config file I defined a plugin for my localhost dev env:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      BASENAME: JSON.stringify("/")
    })
  ],
```

In the Webpack **PROD** config file I defined a plugin for my prod env in a subfolder, i.e. www.example.com/users:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      BASENAME: JSON.stringify("/users/")
    }),
```

And in my react-router definitions I just reference:

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { useBasename } from 'history'
...
<Router history={useBasename(() => browserHistory)({ basename: BASENAME })}>
```

For me a very elegant solution and easy too. It just cost me around five hours of looking around :-)

Answer (score 1):

In React Router V6.

Edit `package.json` and add `homepage : Directory name` key value as follows

```
"homepage" : "https://blog.sangw.in/react-student-management",
```

OR

```
"homepage" : "/react-student-management",
```

and on Routers `BrowserRouter` add `basename : Directory name` as follows

```
<BrowserRouter  basename={'/react-student-management'}>
```

and you are done.

Visit https://blog.sangw.in/react-student-management and app will be deployed and working.

Comment: link broken....

Comment: What if you are using <Routes> instead of <Router>? How do you do it then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```html
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: 'base-name'
}) 

<Router history={history}>
</Router>
```