# getting 404 for links with create-react-app deployed to github pages

Tags: react-router, create-react-app, react-router-redux

I'm trying to deploy a create-react-app to a relative path on GitHub pages with a custom domain. E.g. `www.example.com/myproject`

I'm using `react-router-dom`, `react-router-redux` and `react-router-bootstrap`

I've set homepage to `http://www.example.com/myproject` in `packages.json` (tried `homepage = "."` too) and also configured basename for my history:

```
...
export const history = createHistory({ basename: '/myproject' });
const middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];
...
const composedEnhancers = compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers);
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composedEnhancers);
```

The deployed app works on `www.mydomain.com/myproject` and I can navigate via the app links.

But I got 404 when I try to enter a path directly (eg. `www.example.com/myproject/account`) or if I do browser refresh on a subpage.

Long term goal is to configure different relative paths for dev and prod environments as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42825400/4006001) but first I just need to make it work in deployment.

Comment: u need a server side script to handle the routing for you, example respond to all endpoints with the same index.html

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### Problem: URL gets evaluated on server side

When you enter a new URL into address bar of the browser or refreshes the page, browser requests server (in this case GitHub pages server) for that URL. At this point, client side router (react-router) can't take action as it is not yet loaded for that page. Now server looks for a route that matches `/accounts` won't find it (because routing is done on client side) and returns `404`.

### Solution

If you had control over the server, you can serve `index.html` for all routes.
This is explained in create react app documentation [serving apps with client side routing](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing).
As we don't have that control in case of GitHub pages, We can try these.

**Easy Solution**

Switch from `browserHistory` to `hashHistory`
With this change, your URLs will go from looking like

> www.example.com/myproject/account

to

> www.example.com/myproject/#/account

So it's a bit messy.

**Harder solution**

Get GitHub pages to redirect to `index.html` on all requests. Basically you have to add a `404.html` in your build directory with code to redirect to `index.html`. [More on how to do that](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages).

Create React App has [documentation around client-side routing in GitHub pages](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#notes-on-client-side-routing) too

Comment: thank you. I finally went to a route to deploy to netlify instead. With netlify I just had to add a _redirects file into the root folder , no hacking :)

Comment: @szerte Can you change the question title to something like `getting 404 on hitting routes in GitHub pages or something? It could help people with similar problem to find this easily.

Comment: This link has some nice suggestions [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765). The one that worked for me was using `HashHistory`.

Comment: Thanks. By just using `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter` my problem solved and  now every URL are accessible from outside. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter

Comment: Thanks. By just replacing BrowserRouter with HashRouter fixed my issue.

Comment: it worked, but when i do `refresh webpage` then again getting `same 404 error`, or `<a href>` also not working

Comment: Hi! My index.js file doesn't have code for a Router. Would you please tell me how to add one? Or is that not possible any longer?

Comment: After using `HashRouter` instead of `browserRouter` why it returning ' # '  in url

Answer (score 18):

The best way to solve the issue is create a copy of **index.html** and call it **404.html** for production build. To make it add this to **package.json** scripts:

```
"build": "react-scripts build && cp build/index.html build/404.html"
```

Comment: But when reloading a page (e.g. "/blog"), the app shows the main ("/") again instead of ("/blog").

Comment: Something is wrong with your router

Comment: This solution works but whenever you refresh, you get an annoying "This page seems to be missing" message from your browser, even if the page is properly rendered

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the browser may not have cached the routing code yet so it causes a 404 error if you go to a route other than the index.

Side note if anyone is using **ZEIT Now** to deploy (although gh-pages would be similar); I managed (after a deal of time) to work out how to fix it. It was a bit of an effort so I decided to make an article on it for anyone else who gets stuck.

https://itnext.io/fix-404-error-on-single-page-app-with-zeit-now-b35b8c9eb8fb

Comment: i follwed your article and thats what happened -> 'now' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have control over the server to serve `index.html` from all routes, one option is to use a tool like [react-snap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snap). It takes your React app and renders each route to individual .html files, which you can then publish to GitHub Pages. The individual .html files still include the React app as part of them, so once pages are loaded, React routing takes over as normal.