# 404 error when reloading reactjs site deployed on github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, react-router, github-pages

I recently deployed a reactjs website on github pages using the custom domain -https://titanmarket.co.ke/.

The website works as expected but returns a 404 error when you reload a page. Usually, a user would expect the current page to be displayed on refresh.

Any insight on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57883297/deploying-reactjs-website-on-github-pages-with-routing-results-in-404-error-on-r) [Reference](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing), Also see [this](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages)

Answer (score 0):

Super easy solution for Github pages reload 404 error.

1. in the src/public/ index.js file add this script below to the bottom body:

Index.js
https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages/blob/gh-pages/index.html

2. Create a 404.html file in the root directory:

404.html
https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages/blob/gh-pages/404.html

Read more:

Source:
https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages