# React portal doesn't work after deploying code to gh-page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

I have a React project and the Portals were implemented. Profile.js is the children component of Modal.js. My question is when I run npm start locally, Portals works fine (Profile component can be toggled and it pops up). However, after I deploy the code to gh-pages, the portal doesn't show up (when I click profile, nothing pops up). But when looking at the console, it shows the modal div is inserted. I am wondering how I can fix it? I tried on multiple browsers with the same issue. Thank you

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect, Suspense } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

import 'tachyons';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Slide from './components/Slide/Slide';
import Modal from './components/Modal/Modal';
import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile';
const Ingredient = React.lazy(() => import('./components/Ingredient/Ingredient'));
const RecommendRecipe = React.lazy(() => import('./components/RecommendRecipe/RecommendRecipe')) ;
const Register = React.lazy(() => import('./components/Register/Register'));
const Signin = React.lazy( ()=> import('./components/Signin/Signin')) ;
const SavedRecipes = React.lazy(() => import('./components/SavedRecipes/SavedRecipes')) ;




const initialState = {  
  isLogin: false,
  user: {
    email: '',
    username: '',
    create_on: '',  
    user_id: '',
    dob: '',
    recipes_number: ''
  }
}



function App() {
  const [ user, setUser ] = useState(initialState);
  const [ isProfileOpen, setIsProfileOpen] = useState(false); 


  useEffect(() => {          
    const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) {      
      return fetch('https://warm-reef-43761.herokuapp.com/signin', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: { 
          'content-type': 'Application/json',
          'authorization': token
        }       
      })
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {         
        if (data.id) {         
          return fetch(`https://warm-reef-43761.herokuapp.com/profile/${data.id}`, {
            method: 'get',
            headers: { 
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'authorization': token
            }
          })
          .then(resp => resp.json())
          .then(user => { 
            loadUser(user)            
          })
          .catch(err => console.log('unable to refresh'))
        }
      })
      .catch(console.log)
    }
  }, [])

  const loadUser = (data) => {    
      setUser({
        isLogin: true,
        user: {
          email: data.email,
          username: data.username,
          create_on: data.create_on,
          user_id: data.user_id,
          dob: data.dob,
          recipes_number: data.recipes_number
        }
    });    
  }


  
  const signout = (event) => {   
    setUser(initialState) 
    window.localStorage.removeItem('token') 
   
  }

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setIsProfileOpen(!isProfileOpen)
  }

  
  return (

    <div className="App">
    
        <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>  
          <Navigation 
            isLogin={user.isLogin} signout={signout} toggleModal={toggleModal}/> 
            
          { isProfileOpen && 
            <Modal>
              <Profile  toggleModal={toggleModal} user={user.user} loadUser={loadUser}/>
            </Modal>
          }
          <Suspense fallback={<span>Loading</span>}>
          <Switch>           
            <Route path='/' exact component = {Slide} />
            <Route path='/register' >
              <Register loadUser={loadUser} /> 
            </Route>
            <Route path='/signin'>
              <Signin loadUser={loadUser} />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/foodlist' >
              <Ingredient isLogin={user.isLogin}/>
            </Route>           
            <Route path='/recommendrecipes' >
              <RecommendRecipe user={user.user} loadUser={loadUser} isLogin={user.isLogin} />
            </Route> 
             <Route path='/savedrecipes' >
              <SavedRecipes user={user.user} loadUser={loadUser}/> 
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          </Suspense>
          </Router>  
        
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Modal.js

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './Modal.css'

const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root');

class Modal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.el = document.createElement('div')
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        modalRoot.appendChild(this.el)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        modalRoot.removeChild(this.el)
    }

    render() {
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.el)
    }
}

export default Modal;
```

Profile.js

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

import { useState } from 'react'; 
import './Profile.css'


function Profile({ toggleModal, user, loadUser }) {
  const [ username, setUsername ] = useState(user.username);
  const [ dob, setDob ] = useState(user.dob) 
  
  const onInputChange = (event) => {    
    switch (event.target.name) {
      case 'username': 
        setUsername(event.target.value)
        break
      case 'date':
        setDob(event.target.value)        
        break
      default: 
        return

    }
  } 
  const onEditButton = () => {
    setDob(null)
  
  }

  const onSaveSubmit = (data) => {
    fetch(`https://warm-reef-43761.herokuapp.com/profile/${user.user_id}`, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authorization': window.localStorage.getItem('token')
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ formUpdate: data
      })
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      loadUser({...user, ...data})
      toggleModal()

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

 
  return (  
    <div className='modal'> 
      <div className="col-md-8"> 
        <div className="card mb-3">
          <div className="card-body">           
            <div className="row">              
              <div className="col-sm-11" >              
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-1 mb-3">
                <Button onClick={toggleModal} variant="info" size='sm'>x</Button>
              </div>
            </div>         
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-3 align-self-center">
                <h6 className="mb-0">Username</h6>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-7">
                <input onChange={onInputChange} name='username' placeholder={user.username}/>
              </div>
              
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-3 align-self-center">
                <h6 className="mb-0">Email</h6>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-9 ">
                <h6> {user.email} </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-3 align-self-center">
                <h6 className="mb-0">Date of Birth</h6>
              </div>
              { dob === undefined || dob === null ?
                <div className="col-sm-9  align-self-center">
                  <input type='date' name='date' onChange={onInputChange} />
                </div>
                :
                <>
                  <div className="col-sm-7 align-self-center">
                    <h6>{new Date(dob).toLocaleDateString()}</h6> 
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-2">
                   <Button variant="info" onClick={onEditButton}>Edit</Button>
                  </div>
                </>
              }
              
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-3" >
                <h6 className="mb-0">Saved Recipes</h6>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-9 ">
                {user.recipes_number}
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-3">
                <h6 className="mb-0">Register on</h6>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-9 ">
                {new Date(user.create_on).toLocaleDateString()}
              </div>
            </div>
           
            <hr />
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                <button className="btn btn-info ma2" onClick={() => onSaveSubmit({username, dob})}>Save</button>
                <button className="btn btn-info ma2 " onClick={toggleModal}>Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: Does it work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231618/react-js-page-not-found-on-refresh-or-on-click-on-the-link-directly/69235955#69235955