# Access a specific route in the Client with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple React app hosted in https://alejandromaselli.github.io. Also I've added the React Router module and I've configured a `/signin` route. But when I access directly like this: https://alejandromaselli.github.io/signin It throws me a 404 error.

I should be noted that when I run it locally I can access the url including the `/signin` route. (Such as `http://localhost:3000/signin`)

I will appreciate any support.

Comment: can you post the content of the "package.json" file please?

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056414/getting-404-for-links-with-create-react-app-deployed-to-github-pages

https://medium.com/@bennirus/deploying-a-create-react-app-with-routing-to-github-pages-f386b6ce84c2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter

Relevant link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056414/getting-404-for-links-with-create-react-app-deployed-to-github-pages)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the relative path in package.json

Add this in package.json

```
"homepage": "https://alejandromaselli.github.io/",
```

Now add basename in BrowserRouter

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/"/>
```

This worked for me

For more info visit this link

[Building for Relative Paths](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths)

You can also use hashRouter, but it will make the url look ugly with a hash(#) on it