# React Router Page hosted on GitHub Breaks On Refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have deployed a react app on GitHub the issue is when refresh is done on any of its routed pages I get 404 not found error

[image]

though when the app is in development mode the pages refreshes properly

[Link to the Published App](https://lp-codes.github.io/My-First-React-App/)

i am using switch for routing

```js
< Switch >
  <
  Route exact path = "/"
component = {
  Home
}
/> <
Route exact path = "/todo"
component = {
  Issuetracker
}
/> <
Route exact path = "/weather"
component = {
  Weather
}
/> <
/Switch>
```

Kindly suggest way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Usually it happens due to incorrect configurations in the nodejs server. You supposed to serve your react `index.html` file on every route (otherwise - you will get a 404 error). Like this:

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  const indexHtmlPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html');
  res.sendFile(indexHtmlPath);
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering but for deploying to git i have not used NodeJS or express js , only gh-pages are used can u plz tell in which file i need to place ur code

Comment: I unerstand... Here there is a trick - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056414/getting-404-for-links-with-create-react-app-deployed-to-github-pages (first answer). But, with your own server it is much more easy and clean.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by replacing **browse route with hash route**