# Custom 404 works in local but not in deploy environment on Github pages

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, github-pages, react-router-dom, netlify

**This is my first post here** :) so be cool with me please :)

I try to do a custom 404 with create-react-app V.17.0.2 and react-router-dom V.5.2.0.
It works when i try on local server but something is wrong when i deploy on github-pages.
I have only one `path='/'`, and i want all the others redirect to my `error404` component.

I made one in an other project [lastProject](https://example-prana.netlify.app/) published on Netlify and to fix this i have just create a `_redirects` file in the public folder and write `/*  /index.html  200` inside , it works perfectly.
[Here works Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/01/16/redirect-rules-for-all-how-to-configure-redirects-for-your-static-site/)

i want to find a same easy solution to published on github-pages. I don't want to change the `BrowserRouter` by `Hashrouter` and have a '#' in my URL, and [this solution](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages) is very difficult to me

[My repo if you need it](https://github.com/karastras/Portfolio)

[MyNewProject](https://jerome-burrus.me/)

EDIT: So now i use hashrouter and wait to see an other easy solution

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from '../Header';
import Main from '../Main';
import Footer from '../Footer';
import Error404 from '../Error404'

function App() {  
  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/'>          
          <Header />
          <Main/>         
          <Footer/>
        </Route>
        <Route component={Error404}/>      
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see your comment.
when i try this, i have no error message, my custom 404 appears

Comment: Read [404 when trying to enter a react app route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62050700/2873538). And check [this repo](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages) (and its demo[demo](https://spa-github-pages.rafgraph.dev/)) for help on "How to create a custom 404 page that redirects to index.html page" when using github pages.

Comment: Yep i saw it too but the way to add a 404 htlm file in own project is a little difficult to me. I thought there is an easier way like with Netlify, just add a file `_redirects` in `/public` and put `/*  /index.html  200` and that's all folks....

Comment: i think i will migrate my site on Netlify and that's all, i don't want to use hashrouter and have an '#' in my URL and the 404html way is very difficult to me, so...

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to configure `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

https://gist.github.com/alexsasharegan/173878f9d67055bfef63449fa7136042

Comment: Hello , thanks to your fast answer
i added it in root directory and deploy the site but it not working to me...

Comment: It works!
https://ibb.co/fpdqBtd

use CTRL + F5 to see it

Comment: No this is my last projects , and 404 works without htaccess but not on my actual project https://jerome-burrus.me/
I edited the post to no trouble like that

Comment: Oh, that's right
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056414/getting-404-for-links-with-create-react-app-deployed-to-github-pages

Comment: yep i saw this post today but i don't understand why it don't work on this project like this and with the last there is no issue... its the same issue on with github and netlify while my last project is published on Netlify.... and with the hasrouter the URL become ugly... but i will try it
the harder solution is more complcate for me but i will try it too

Comment: With the Hasrouter replace the BrowserRouter it works ! but now my url is uggly...

Comment: Ok now i know what's the difference between my last and actual project, i have edited this difference in my post, there is an file added to Netlify , the`_redirects` file